# How can i get "latitude" and "longitude" after integrating google maps in my Reactjs web app?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers, react-map-gl

i'm making a **Reactjs** app where i want to show google maps in  app... i want to implement the following

(1) my app will want permissions from user **to get his current position and get the "latitude" and "longitude"** and save them.

or

(2) user selects the marker on map and i want to get those latitude and longitude points.

first is more important. Please help me out. please thanks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4z4hxEHlsxc

i saw this video and this was helpful but **he didn't teach about (1) problem**.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/samma89/pen/gyLgEJ). You can get your first task done. For the second task, read the documentation. It's pretty straight forward. Links are below.

[Markers documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

[Events documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)

Also, this [library](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/) is very good at handling google maps. take a look.

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.map = null;
    this.marker = null;

    this.state = {
      currentLocation: {
        lat: 0.0,
        lng: 0.0
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (navigator && navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
        const coords = pos.coords;
        this.setState({
          currentLocation: {
            lat: coords.latitude,
            lng: coords.longitude
          }
        });
        this.setPin(coords.latitude, coords.longitude)
      });

      this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
    }else{
      //TODO:
    }
  }

  setPin(lat, lng) {
    if(this.map) {
      this.map.setCenter({lat: lat, lng: lng});

      if(this.marker) {
        this.marker.setMap(null);
        this.marker = null;
      }

      this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
        map: this.map,
        title: 'Current Location'
      });

    }else{
      console.log("Map has not loaded yet")
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="app">
        {this.state.currentLocation.lat } / {this.state.currentLocation.lng}
        <div id="map"></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

Comment: thanks you so much.
can you please help me how to extract a reusable component from this.
Like i have highorder component <App> where i have "location:{ lat : ... , lng:... }"  state. 
i want to render this.
<div>
<Map  />
</div>
i want get to get latitude and longitude from this "Map" component.
please help me please.

Comment: can you send me a link of this which you have implemented? or create a Codepen and send me?

Comment: i just used your link which u mentioned above.

https://codepen.io/samma89/pen/gyLgEJ

Comment: it says can' read property 'map' of undefined. 
and also, u have used <div id="map"></div> . but in reactjs we dont deal with Real DOM. please help me out.

Comment: u have not used "GOOGLE API KEY" .  and it says "This page can't load Google Maps correctly."

Answer (score -2):

**Use this library**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-geocode

```
import Geocode from "react-geocode";

/// set Google Maps Geocoding API for purposes of quota management
Geocode.setApiKey("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
Geocode.setLangu`enter code here`age("en");

// Get address from latidude & longitude.
Geocode.fromLatLng("48.8583701", "2.2922926").then(
  response => {
    const address = response.results[0].formatted_address;
    console.log(address);
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error);
  }
);

// Get latidude & longitude from address.
Geocode.fromAddress("Eiffel Tower").then(
  response => {
    const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
    console.log(lat, lng);
  },
  error => {
    console.error(error);
  }
);
```